# Oracle sql get two or more value in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table emp(
emp_id number primary key,
emp varchar2(10),
emp_date date,
deptno number
)


Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (1,'Ronaldo','01.01.2021.',1);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (2,'Ronaldo','02.01.2021.',1);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (3,'Ronaldo','03.01.2021.',1);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (4,'Messi','01.01.2021.',1);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (5,'Messi','02.01.2021.',2);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (6,'Ronaldo','04.01.2021.',2);
Insert into emp (emp_id, emp,emp_date,deptno) values (7,'Messi','04.01.2021.',2);




             01.01.2021       |   02.01.2021      |   03.01.2021  |     04.01.2021 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deptno 1     Ronaldo, Messi       Ronaldo, Messi      Ronaldo
 
deptno 2     null                 Messi               null              Ronaldo, Messi
```

Need result as display in above table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `listagg` with `CASE WHEN`

**Query 1**:

```
select deptno,
       listagg((CASE WHEN emp_date = '01.01.2021.' Then emp END),',') within group( order by emp_id ) "01.01.2021.",
       listagg((CASE WHEN emp_date = '02.01.2021.' Then emp END),',') within group( order by emp_id ) "02.01.2021.",
       listagg((CASE WHEN emp_date = '03.01.2021.' Then emp END),',') within group( order by emp_id ) "03.01.2021.", 
       listagg((CASE WHEN emp_date = '04.01.2021.' Then emp END),',') within group( order by emp_id ) "04.01.2021."
from emp 
group by deptno
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/943b9/6/0)**:

```
| DEPTNO |   01.01.2021. | 02.01.2021. | 03.01.2021. |   04.01.2021. |
|--------|---------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|
|      1 | Ronaldo,Messi |     Ronaldo |     Ronaldo |        (null) |
|      2 |        (null) |       Messi |      (null) | Ronaldo,Messi |
```